# About the optimal solution to an Integer-linear-programming (ILP) problem

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

Is it true that the optimal solution to an ILP problem must be one of the neighboring points of the points on the boundaries of the corresponding relaxed LP problem? Is so, how to prove it?

That is, let V be the set of vertices in the feasible region.
For each vertex v=(v1, v2, ..., v_n), we call w=(w1, w2, ..., w_n) an integer neighbor of v if for every k, w_k = ceiling(v_k) or w_k = floor(v_k).
Let Neighbor(V) ={w | w is a neighbor of v and v is on the boundary of the feasible region}. 
Is the hypothesis true? If so, prove it. If not, give a counterexample.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and where you get stuck. You’ll have a better chance of getting good answers if you show that you put in some effort before you posted your problem here.